# Bootstrap Datepicker with Modal returning null

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar, bootstrap-modal

I m using bootstrap year calender and model - The problem is datepicker is not working and start date/end date is coming as null.

On click on the date in calendar, modal will open on the modal i have start date and end date when i try to get date it is returing null.

Kindly help

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <link href="../../staticFiles/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../staticFiles/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../../staticFiles/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../../staticFiles/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../staticFiles/css/bootstrap-year-calendar.css" />
  <link href="../../staticFiles/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../staticFiles/css/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="../../staticFiles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../staticFiles/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../staticFiles/js/onCallCalendar.js"></script>

  <script>
    function editEvent(event) {
      $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(event ? event.id : '');
      $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(event ? event.name : '');
      $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(event ? event.location : '');
      $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('option', 'update', event ? event.startDate : '');
      $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('option', 'update', event ? event.endDate : '');
      $('#event-modal').modal("show");
    }

    function deleteEvent(event) {
      var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

      for (var i in dataSource) {
        if (dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
          dataSource.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }

      $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    function saveEvent() {
      var event = {
        id: $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(),
        name: $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(),
        location: $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(),
        startDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker("getDate"),
        endDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker("getDate")
      }

      var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

      if (event.id) {
        for (var i in dataSource) {
          if (dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
            dataSource[i].name = event.name;
            dataSource[i].location = event.location;
            dataSource[i].startDate = event.startDate;
            dataSource[i].endDate = event.endDate;
          }
        }
      } else {
        var newId = 0;
        for (var i in dataSource) {
          if (dataSource[i].id > newId) {
            newId = dataSource[i].id;
          }
        }

        newId++;
        event.id = newId;

        dataSource.push(event);
        console.log("data is pushed to Datasource");
        console.log(dataSource);
      }

      $('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
      $('#event-modal').modal('hide');
    }

    $(function() {

      var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

      $('#calendar').calendar({
        enableContextMenu: true,
        enableRangeSelection: true,
        contextMenuItems: [{
            text: 'Update',
            click: editEvent
          },
          {
            text: 'Delete',
            click: deleteEvent
          }
        ],
        selectRange: function(e) {
          editEvent({
            startDate: e.startDate,
            endDate: e.endDate
          });
        },
        mouseOnDay: function(e) {
          if (e.events.length > 0) {
            var content = '';

            for (var i in e.events) {
              content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">' +
                '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '">' + e.events[i].name + '</div>' +
                '<div class="event-location">' + e.events[i].location + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            }

            $(e.element).popover({
              trigger: 'manual',
              container: 'body',
              html: true,
              content: content
            });

            $(e.element).popover('show');
          }
        },
        mouseOutDay: function(e) {
          if (e.events.length > 0) {
            $(e.element).popover('hide');
          }
        },
        dayContextMenu: function(e) {
          $(e.element).popover('hide');
        },
        renderEnd: function(e) {
          var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
          $('#calendar .month-container').each(function(idx, el) {
            console.log(currentMonth);
            if (idx < currentMonth - 1) {
              $(this).css("display", "none");
            }
            if (idx > currentMonth + 1) {
              $(this).css("display", "none");
            }
          });
        },
        dataSource: [{
            id: 0,
            name: 'Google I/O',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 29)
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
            location: 'New Orleans, LA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 16),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 19)
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Microsoft Build Developer Conference',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 3, 29),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 1)
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Apple Special Event',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1)
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Apple Keynote',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9)
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Chrome Developer Summit',
            location: 'Mountain View, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 18)
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'F8 2015',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 25),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 26)
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'Yahoo Mobile Developer Conference',
            location: 'New York',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 25),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 26)
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            name: 'Android Developer Conference',
            location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 1),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 4)
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            name: 'LA Tech Summit',
            location: 'Los Angeles, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17)
          }
        ]
      });

      $('#save-event').click(function() {
        saveEvent();
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div class="modal modal-fade" id="event-modal" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Event
                </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" name="event-index" value="">
          <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="min-date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <input name="event-name" type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="min-date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Location</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <input name="event-location" type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="min-date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dates</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="input-group input-daterange" data-provide="datepicker">
                  <input name="event-start-date" type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                  <input name="event-end-date" type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">
                    Save
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It has been a while since this was asked but just in case someone needs it. The problem is that you are not including the datepicker script:

```
<script src="../../staticFiles/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

This is the picker they are using: [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)
. Download it and add it to your project.

EDIT:
Here a fiddle if needs it: https://jsfiddle.net/William_/4520t0dq/